# I'm using a hidden input field to move data, is there a better way?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I'm using a hidden input tag to pass a variable to a PHP script. This is the tag,

```
<input type="hidden" name="batch" value="<?php echo $batch; ?>">
```

The variable `$batch` is generated on the page upon user input and this variable needs to go a script which is why I have used a hidden input tag.

I feel this isn't very secure as the value left by the variable `$batch` can be changed using the developer toolbar or firebug.

To make it more clear,

```
<input type="hidden" name="batch" value="7">
```

is what I see using firebug. I can change the value of `$batch` and then submit the form.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You've never heard of sessions?

Comment: @JohnConde I have, but I'm not sure how would I use it in this case. I need the script to run when a button is clicked and that's why I use a form.

Comment: If you can't or won't use sessions, and you want your hidden field to be tamper-proof, you can always encrypt it. If someone tampers with the value, decryption fails and that user did something they weren't supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sessions too. That'd be more secure, in my opinion since it can't be viewed on the client side.

Try this:

```
$_SESSION['batch'] = $batch;
```

Once the session is stored, you can access this value in any page you want by writing:

```
echo $_SESSION['batch'];   // Output: 7
```

Comment: The script needs to be run when a button is clicked. Even if I use sessions I'll have to echo it out somewhere right? Or I'm I missing something?